# How do i get all occurrences of my parser rule in ANTLRs java runtime?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm working at a code-formatter in Java for my own **ANTLR** Grammar and now want to work on formatting one special rule.

What I want, is to somehow iterate over all **occurrences** of one of my parser rules (`if_stmt` to be specific).
I'm working with ANTLR4 and the Java runtime.

---

This is the smallest version of my **grammar** for this issue:

```
stmt_block
:
    EOF
    | stmt_list EOF
;

stmt_list
:
    stmt
    | stmt_list stmt
;

stmt
:

    if_stmt
    |  RETURN SEMICOLON NEWLINE?
;

if_stmt
:
    IF BRACKET_OPEN expr BRACKET_CLOSED CBRACKET_OPEN stmt_list CBRACKET_CLOSED
;

expr
:
    TRUE
;
```

This is how my format function looks so far

```java
private String formatCode(String input) 
{
    // Parse the input
    MyLexer lex = new MyLexer(new CaseChangingCharStream(
        CharStreams.fromString(input), true));

    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    tokens.fill();
    MyParser pars = new MyParser(tokens);
    Stmt_blockContext stmt_blockContext = pars.stmt_block();

    stmt_blockContext.children.forEach(parseTree->{
        //Iterate over the parseTree to get all if_stmtContext's and modify them
    });


    // Then return the modified contexts text
    return stmt_blockContext.getText();
}
```

This is how I've gotten so far, and I know I'm asking for someone to just solve my problem, but I am stuck at this and have no Idea how to proceed.

**Any** help is appreciated!

Comment: You should look into listeners or visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use only a parser for any formatting task, unless you want it to be able to work only with valid input. Formatting is mostly rewriting whitespaces, for which a lexer is much better suited. See my [ANTLR4 plugin for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/Formatter.ts) for an example how to implement a code formatter. This one is for ANTLR4 grammars, but the same principles apply for any other programming language.